# Getting a gradle build error. Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, build.gradle

Got this error after updating my Kotlin plugin on android studio.

```
package com.inovate.kotlin.module3.decorations

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    makeDecorations()
}

fun makeDecorations() {
    val d1 = Decorations("rectangle", 56, 20)
}

data class Decorations(val shape : String, val weight : Int, val area : Int)
```

This is the error:

```
* Where:
Initialization script '/private/var/folders/bn/st769wd16nv1d5_wccw8_tm00000gn/T/DecorationsKt_main__2.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ': app'.
> Could not create task ':app:DecorationsKt.main()'.
   > SourceSet with name 'main' not found.
```

When I run a stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer$TaskCreationException: Could not create task ':app:DecorationsKt.main()'.

Caused by: org.gradle.api.UnknownDomainObjectException: SourceSet with name 'main' not found.
```

I have updated all my dependencies, invalidated caches and restarted, and tried to delete my .idea folder but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This happens during file corrosion so some few steps to fix the issue

In intellij idea go to build >
Step 1:
clean project
Step 2:
Rebuild
If it doesn't work
Locate to project > delete .idea folder
Finally invalidate cache restart

Comment: I have tried it and it still does not work :(

Comment: Ah, ok make sure you have deleted .idea folder after restart ide then the next step would be remove the last kotlin running configuration (alt + delete) in Run/Debug configuration finally run it from run gutter(icon in main function)                              if these steps won't work recreate new kotlin file(not a project) @jeanlucrotolo

Comment: Still did not work - I deleted the .idea folder, invalidate cache restart, removed the file from the kotlin running configuration then attempted to run from the gutter icon. Still no luck - I even created a new file and new project.

Comment: have you update your gradle @jeanlucrotolo

Comment: @jeanlucrotolo I mean gradle wrapper / gradle deamon

Comment: Yes I have updated the Gradle wrapper `buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"`

Comment: I have managed to get a temporary solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129776/7952086

Comment: Good to hear that 